# Which continuous function of n variables between 1 to n takes maximum value when variables are permutations of 1,2,3...n?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, entropy, maxima-minima

I need a function of the form

```
f(x1,x2,...,xn)
where 0 <= xi <= n
```

such that a global optimum of f has variable values being permutations of {1,2,3...,n).

Is there such a function?

Comment: I need a function with n! optimums i.e. every possible permutation of {1..n} has exactly same maximum value.
( Oops! I don't know how  I deleted your comment! Can you reinsert it? )

Comment: sorry wrong manip deleted my first comment. also I'm wondering about that maximum.maximum over what ? Because for a function f(x,y)=f(y,x) these are just dummy parameters. so are the xi fixed or are they variables ?

Comment: A trivial and not very useful answer is the following polynomial: $\prod\limits_\sigma\left(\sum\limits_i(x_i-\sigma_i)^2\right)$, where the product is taken over all permutations $\sigma$.

Comment: @zwim each xi is a continuous variable between 1 to n

Comment: My question stands, over what are you taking the maximum ? Because $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ or $f(\sigma(x_1,...,x_n))$ are the same ! These $x_i$ are only dummy names, it doesn't matter that you shuffle them. I mean $f(x,y)=\tan(x)/e^y$ or $f(foo,bar)=\tan(foo)/e^{bar}$ are the same right ? I do not understand your question. Is the range verified by each $x_i$ the variable parameter that induce different maxima, because over $\mathbb R^n$ nothing changes ?